# How can I use vagrant on an existing machine?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have:

- a machine on amazon I can ssh to
- Vagrantfile and resources it uses to automate a process.

How can I tell my vagrant to use the machine I have? (I don't want to spin a new machine)

currently doing stuff manually. 
also cannot use docker (project requirement).

Answer (score 1):

I found this awesome vagrant plugin that answers my needs

https://github.com/tknerr/vagrant-managed-servers

Answer (score 0):

You can't

Basically, vagrant needs a box to create the VM to work with. You would not be able to create a base box from your running EC2 instance ([`vagrant package`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html) only works with VirtualBox)

You would be able to spin new EC2 instance from a specific EC2 box (or create a box yourself for the EC2 provider) but for your existing instance, you'll need to continue working with ssh